# Replacing unwanted characters with regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have this string which is on one line:

```
https[:]//sometest[.]com,http[:]//differentt,est.net,https://lololo.com
```

Note that I purposely placed `,` into the second URL. I am trying to replace the `,` where the `http(s)` meets. So far I tried this:

```
pattern_src = r"http(.*)"
for i, line_src in enumerate(open("/Users/test/Documents/tools/dump/email.txt")):
    for match in re.finditer(pattern_src, line_src):
        mal_url = (match.group())
source_ = mal_url

string = source_
for ch in ["[" , "]"]:
    for c in [","]:
        string = string.replace(c,"\n")
        string = string.replace(ch,"")
        with open("/Users/test/Documents/tools/dump/urls.txt", 'w') as file:
                file.write(string)
print(string)
```

But you can clearly see it will replace all the `,` in the string. So my question is, how would I go around replacing just the `,` before the `http` and have every `http` URL on a new line?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? `re.sub(r',(?=http)', '\n', s)` where `s` is the string input

Comment: @ Sundeep that's exactly it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> s = 'https[:]//sometest[.]com,http[:]//differentt,est.net,https://lololo.com'
>>> print(re.sub(r',(?=http)', '\n', s))
https[:]//sometest[.]com
http[:]//differentt,est.net
https://lololo.com
```

`,(?=http)` will match `,` only if it is followed by `http`. Here `(?=http)` is a positive lookahead assertion, which allows to check for conditions without consuming those characters.

See [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) for details on lookarounds or my book: https://learnbyexample.github.io/py_regular_expressions/lookarounds.html

Comment: That's the solution I was looking for, very appreciated this. Thanks @Sundeep